# Chart that shows the number of items in each SLA

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to determine the number of items in a particular range of SLA. I was thinking of grouping them up, so having:

- 1-5 hours
- 5-10
- 10-15
- 15-24
- 24-48
- 48+

The only problem with this is that I don't have the groups set up already.

I have a CreatedTime on each item, and a ResolvedTime. How do I turn this into a set "1-5 hours" using formula? And then grouping whatever is outputted...?

I was thinking of using a bar chart for this.

I am also very new to CR.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula to group on

```
local numbervar mindiff := datediff("n",{table.created},{table.resolved});

select mindiff
 case 0 to 300 :  "1-5"
 case 301 to 600 : "5-10"
 case 601 to 900 : "10-15"
 case 901 to 1440 : "15-24"
 case 1441 to 2880 : "24-48"
 default: "48+"
```

Edit: If you're more comfortable working with hours instead of minutes, you can pass "h" into datediff() instead of "n". If nothing else, it'll make your cases easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a formula to group on; the formula would be something like:

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar SLATime; //Define a variable to hold time difference

SLATime:= ResolvedTime - CreatedTime; //you need to use time/date functions to return the hours difference - consult crystal documentation

if SLATime <=5 then
"One"
Elseif SLATime>5 and SLATime<=10 then
"Two"
Elseif
...
...
...
Else "48+"
```

Then group on this formula.